# URL Redirect / URL Masking

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have a page.

http://sciconference.net/viewjc.php?id=c5

I want when some body comes on this page the URL Bar shows the url

http://sciconference.net/ICEEC

means URL masking... I try .htaccess but no success please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating `.htaccess` and putting the following in it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ICEEC$ viewjc.php?id=c5 [L]
RewriteRule ^ICEEC/$ viewjc.php?id=c5 [L]  

</IfModule>
```

Make sure that the `viewjc.php` is at the same directory as your `.htaccess`

If you're just trying to change URL address bar when someone visits particular page of your website, add this to your PHP code page:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/viewjc.php?id=c5') {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.history.pushState("", "", "/ICEEC");</script>';
}
```

Everytime when a user goes to `viewjc.php?id=c5` your URL will be changed.

Besides you could again use `.htaccess` for doing that!

Comment: Done but not working...

Comment: Could you tell me more than, not working? What does it say?

Comment: it's same as before

http://sciconference.net/viewjc.php?id=c5

Comment: actually all conferences coming through admin panal. and the client don't want viewjc.php?id=c5.. he need the URL as sciconferences.net/iceec

Comment: Then you must check your server's settings and that your Apache `mod_rewrite` is enabled? Is it Apache or maybe it's something else?

Comment: ya I just check with server team it's enabled..  ya aAache...

Comment: please help me out i am totally stuck.. I asked many developers but no success.

Comment: If I go to http://sciconference.net/ICEEC. It's working! What else would you want?

Comment: I just open php info into index page please check it's open or closed..

http://sciconference.net/

Comment: sciconference.net/ICEEC   i did this through iframe.. and user don't know the this direct add.. user comes from conferences page. and if click iceec link so URL bar shows. sciconference.net/ICEEC

Comment: I did this using 
<iframe id="tree" name="tree" src="http://sciconference.net/viewjc.php?id=c5" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="auto"></iframe>

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: In simple words. if somebody comes to "sciconference.net/viewjc.php?id=c5" the address bar show "sciconference.net/iceec"

URL Masking...

Comment: I understood. I will update my answer shortly!

Comment: Thank you so much liia.. love you :)